# Error when parsing redis aggregation reply. redigo: unexpected element type for Strings, got type []interface {} on reply position 4

Tags: go, redis

I use [redigo](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gomodule/redigo) to use redis in golang

I have tried to use group with reducerTOLIST  but I got the following error: `Error parsing Aggregate Reply: redigo: unexpected element type for Strings, got type []interface {} on reply position 4`

My request: `FT.AGGREGATE user "toto" limit 0 1000 GROUPBY 1 @u_name reduce TOLIST 1 @_id AS u_id`

Do you know if there is another way to do this request please ?

Thank!

Comment: can you please share your go code, based on the error message the issue is clearly located on the source code

Comment: Thank you for you reply, here my go code  `redisearch.AggregateQuery{Max: 1000}.GroupBy(redisearch.GroupBy{Fields: []string{"@u_name"}, Reducers: []redisearch.Reducer{{Alias: "u_id", Name: redisearch.GroupByReducerToList, Args: []string{"@u_id"}}}`